# How to solve simple linear programming problem with lpSolve

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to maximize the function $a_1x_1 + \cdots +a_nx_n$ subject to the constraints $b_1x_1 + \cdots + b_nx_n \leq c$ and $x_i \geq 0$ for all $i$. For the toy example below, I've chosen $a_i = b_i$, so the problem is to maximize $0x_1 + 25x_2 + 50x_3 + 75x_4 + 100x_5$ given $0x_1 + 25x_2 + 50x_3 + 75x_4 + 100x_5 \leq 100$. Trivially, the maximum value of the objective function should be 100, but when I run the code below I get a solution of 2.5e+31. What's going on?

```
library(lpSolve)

a <- seq.int(0, 100, 25)
b <- seq.int(0, 100, 25)
c <- 100


optimal_val <- lp(direction = "max", 
                  objective.in = a,
                  const.mat = b, 
                  const.dir = "<=", 
                  const.rhs = c, 
                  all.int = TRUE)

optimal_val
```

Answer (score 1):

`b` is not a proper matrix. You should do, before the `lp` call:

```
b <- seq.int(0, 100, 25)
b <- matrix(b,nrow=1)
```

That will give you an explicit 1 x 5 matrix:

```
> b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0   25   50   75  100
```

Now you will see:

```
> optimal_val
Success: the objective function is 100
```

Background: by default R will consider a vector as a column matrix:

```
> matrix(c(1,2,3))
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```